# $ Undefined on (Node+Express+Pug+JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

A Newbie question for sure, but I'd appreciate any help, as I'm completely stuck (ie, I tried everything I could find without success).
When I try to use Jquery, i get "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".
My project structure is:

> `bin/www
>      public
>         javascripts
>         stylesheets
>      routes
>         index.js
>      views
>         layout.pug
>         ...
>      app.js`

layout.pug, where I try to load CDN jquery is:

```
    doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    title= title
    //- bootstrap CSS
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    integrity='sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u' crossorigin='anonymous')
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css')

    //- my Styling CSS
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')

  body

    block content
    script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js")
    script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous")
    script(src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'
          integrity='sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa' crossorigin='anonymous')

    script(src='/javascripts/jquery-3.3.1.js')
    script(src='routes/index.js')
```

My index.js file is the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

$(function () {
  alert('JavaScript Loaded!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Finally, in my app.js file these are some relevant lines:

```
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// Set Static Paths
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: have you tried removing the slash     script(src='/javascripts/jquery-3.3.1.js') before javascripts

Comment: Yes, I have, but that's not the problem. As I use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`without slash after public I need to include it before `javascripts`. Evenmore, I wanted jquery to be loaded through the CDN, that line is almost redundant, just to be sure that jQuery was loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you don't know `server-side-rendering` vs `client-side-rendering`.

Expressjs is `server-side-rendering`. so you don't call jQuery in index.js

If you call jQuery, you do this. `var $ = require('jQuery');`

reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jQuery#nodejs

Comment: You're right, I'm a newbie. But in this case, index.js (where I use $) is client-side, not app.js which is server-side.

Comment: I thought that index.js (where I use $) was client-side, but I was messing things up. I thing you've solved it. Thanks

Comment: this is difficult thing. I recommend to read this page. 
simply your server executes nodejs on the other hand client's browser executes html page. https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/2504541-ultra-fast-applications-using-node-js/2504696-node-js-what-is-it-for-exactly